# Maven Import AAR Classes.jar

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea.  I'm trying to import couch-lite into my project using Maven.

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>*</groupId>
<artifactId>*</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.couchbase.lite</id>
        <name>couchbase-lite</name>
        <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.lite</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-lite-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, I can't access the classes.jar of the aar library.  Does anyone have any idea how I can reference the files in that jar?

Comment: What are you asking exactly?  Do you want to see the source of the classes.jar or do you just want to use classes that are in the classes.jar?  If you want to use the classes, then they should 'just be there', but you might not be able to browse that jar file via Intellij.

Comment: I'm following the getting started that couchbase-lite has.  To create the database, you need to import `com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidContext`. This file is in the classes.jar (along with others).  I get compiler errors trying to reference these files.

Comment: To be clear, I am not an android developer, so, please take everything I say with a grain of salt.  I have read [one article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile-couchbase/c9nXHqoKWX0) that says that you must extract the classes.jar file form the .arr file.  BUT, looking at the repository that you've referenced, why not try [couchbase-lite-java-core](http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/lite/couchbase-lite-java-core/) instead of [couchbase-lite-android](http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/lite/couchbase-lite-android/) in your pom file?

Comment: `couchbase-lite-android` has a dependency on core, so if I import android, core also get's imported.  'couchbase-lite-android` is only a few files.  I thought the IDE and maven were supposed to parse the aar file correctly, but I guess that might not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using `Gradle` to build the project.  The build times are much longer, but all the libraries are being loaded correctly.